# VBA to check the specific columns are exists in the sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Before running into main procedure here i am checking whether some specific columns are exists in the sheet1 or not, But the problem is in that raw data sheet columns like "Employee Name" & "Designation" are in that sheet, but when run the below code it is giving an message "Not Found" and it is coming out of that loop, Can you please help me on this issue.

```
Dim rngX As Range
Sub Colvalidation1()

Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S1").Find("Work Geography", lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
Call Colvalidation2
Else
    MsgBox "Work Geography - Column Not Found"
End If
End Sub

Sub Colvalidation2()

Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S1").Find("Work Country",
lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
Call Colvalidation3
Else
    MsgBox "Work Country - Column Not Found"
End If
End Sub

Sub Colvalidation3()

Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S1").Find("Project #", lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
Call Colvalidation4
Else
    MsgBox "Project # - Column Not Found"
End If
End Sub

Sub Colvalidation4()

Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S1").Find("Project Name", lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
Call Colvalidation5
Else
    MsgBox "Project Name - Column Not Found"
End If
End Sub

Sub Colvalidation5()

Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S1").Find("Employee #", lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
Call Colvalidation8
Else
    MsgBox "Employee # - Column Not Found"
End If
End Sub

Sub Colvalidation6()

Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S1").Find("Employee Name", lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
Call Colvalidation7
Else
    MsgBox "Employee Name - Column Not Found"
End If
End Sub

Sub Colvalidation7()

Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S1").Find("Designation", lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
Call Colvalidation8
Else
    MsgBox "Designation - Column Not Found"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i think you are not calling `sub Colvalidation6`. BTW instead of using that many sub ..you can simply use Loop and do this in one go

Comment: Actually in the Sub Colvalidation5 if the condition is true then i will go to Sub Colvalidation6 but due to that issue i am skipping Colvalidation6 & Colvalidation7 and directly calling the Sub Colvalidation8. Even that column two columns are available in the sheet also it telling "Not Available", Because i am not familiar on working with loop.

Comment: In number 5 you are calling number 8, number 6 and 7 are not being called in your code.

Comment: i will post answer using loop if you are interested

Comment: Hello Maddy,  I am interested on using loo and waiting your answer.

Comment: Hello UGP, I am not calling 6 and 7 because in the above code even that column two columns are available in the sheet also it telling "Not Available"  that is why i am skipping Colvalidation6 & Colvalidation7 and directly calling the Sub Colvalidation8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to duplicate code

use an `Array` to hold your column header to search for and one helper `Sub` or `Function` to call for each of them

if you want to stop at the first found column header, the following would do:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rngX As Range
Sub main()
    Dim vals As Variant, val As Variant
    vals = Array("Work Geography", "Work Country", "Project #", "Project Name", "Employee #", "Employee Name")

    Dim rngToSearchIn As Range
    Set rngToSearchIn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S1")

    For Each val In vals
        If Colvalidation(rngToSearchIn, val) Then Exit For
    Next
    If Not rngX Is Nothing Then MsgBox "found " & val & " in " & rngX.Address
End Sub

Function Colvalidation(rng As Range, value As Variant) As Boolean
    Set rngX = rng.Find(what:=value, lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Colvalidation = Not rngX Is Nothing
    If Not Colvalidation Then MsgBox value & " - Column Not Found"
End Function
```

While if you want to process all column headers, then the following would do:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rngX As Range

Sub main()
    Dim vals As Variant, val As Variant
    vals = Array("Work Geography", "Work Country", "Project #", "Project Name", "Employee #", "Employee Name")

    Dim rngToSearchIn As Range
    Set rngToSearchIn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S1")

    For Each val In vals
        Colvalidation rngToSearchIn, val
    Next
End Sub

Sub Colvalidation(rng As Range, value As Variant)
    Set rngX = rng.Find(what:=value, lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If rngX Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox value & " - Column Not Found"
    Else
        MsgBox "found " & value & " in " & rngX.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Friend, Your Code also works perfect. For one question i got an answer in the different approach. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh That's great my issue is resolved, Once again Thank you so much my dear friend.

Comment: I have a question, In your code it says if it false means it will terminate the session and if all the are available means in that sheet1 means it suppose to call the another module, but that is not in your code.

Comment: I don't get you. There are two "codes" 1) the first code consists of a "Main" sub and a helper function ("Colvalidation"). This "code" stops at the first found header of those listed in the `array` . 2) the second code consists of a "Main" sub and a helper sub ("Colvalidation"). This "code" will search and report about _all_ headers listed in the array and report. So which "code" are you referring to and what's the actual issue?

Comment: I am referring this code:-                                                                                  Sub Colvalidation(rng As Range, value As Variant)
    Set rngX = rng.Find(what:=value, lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If rngX Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox value & " - Column Not Found"
    Else
        MsgBox "found " & value & " in " & rngX.Address
    End If
   End Sub

Comment: Instead of "MsgBox "found " & value & " in " & rngX.Address", Can i call another module.

Comment: yes you can. if your Sub to be called is named after "MySub" , then just code  `Else:         MySub`

Comment: Hi, When i tried to call this module "Final" for each column it running one time, I means say for 5 columns it is running 5 times, How to fix this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166449/discussion-between-gyana-prakash-and-displayname).

Answer (score 4):

Please try this

```
    Sub Find_Columns()

    Dim rngToSearch As Range
    Dim WhatToFind As Variant
    Dim iCtr As Long

    Set rngToSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S1")

    WhatToFind = Array("Project Name", "Employee #", "Employee Name") 'add all Column header that you want to check

    With rngToSearch
        For iCtr = LBound(WhatToFind) To UBound(WhatToFind)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngToSearch, WhatToFind(iCtr)) > 0 Then ' Check if column is preset or not
                    MsgBox WhatToFind(iCtr) & " Column Found" ' Pop-up msg if column is exist
            Else
                    MsgBox WhatToFind(iCtr) & " Column Not Found" ' Pop-up msg if column is Not Found
            End If
        Next
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Maddy, Your Code works perfect...Thank you so much.